# what mysql query is better?

Tags: mysql, performance, select

i got 2 mysql queries, that retrieve the same data?, what one do you think is better to use and why? taking into account standards, and better code etc. sorry if this is a stupid question, but im a curious cat! so here goes:

QUERY 1:

```
SELECT *
FROM
((
  SELECT u.username, u.picture, m.id, m.user_note, m.reply_id, m.reply_name, m.dt
  FROM   relationships r
  JOIN   notes m ON m.user_id = r.leader
  JOIN   user u ON r.leader = u.user_id
  WHERE  r.listener ='2'
)
UNION ALL
(
  SELECT u.username, u.picture, m.id, m.user_note, m.reply_id, m.reply_name, m.dt
  FROM   notes m
  JOIN   user u ON m.user_id = u.user_id
  WHERE  u.user_id ='2'
)) d
WHERE    d.dt < '2010-09-20_131830'
ORDER BY d.dt DESC
```

QUERY 2:

```
SELECT u.username, u.picture, m.id, m.user_note, m.reply_id, m.reply_name, m.dt
FROM notes m
INNER JOIN user u
ON m.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE (m.user_id = '2'
OR m.user_id IN (
   SELECT r.leader
   FROM relationships r
   WHERE r.listener ='2'))
AND dt < '2010-09-20_131830'
ORDER BY dt DESC
```

Comment: Why not try doing an EXPLAIN for each query to determine which one MySQL thinks is the more efficient, or which do you find easier to read?

Comment: i used explain but i dont understand what they are saying!! plus the first query took `0.0013 sec` AND the second query took `0.0200` seconds!

Comment: see e.g. this for a quick intro to `EXPLAIN`: http://www.learn-mysql-tutorial.com/OptimizeQueries.cfm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the `UNION ALL` version much easier to understand (that could be me offcourse) but I'd rewrite it as below.

Adding the `AND m.dt < '2010-09-20_131830` to each part should give you a better performance.
You could run it a few times and verify if it makes a difference.

```
SELECT  u.username
        , u.picture
        , m.id
        , m.user_note
        , m.reply_id
        , m.reply_name
        , m.dt 
FROM    relationships r 
        INNER JOIN notes m ON m.user_id = r.leader 
        INNER JOIN user u ON r.leader = u.user_id 
WHERE   r.listener ='2' 
        AND m.dt < '2010-09-20_131830' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT  u.username
        , u.picture
        , m.id
        , m.user_note
        , m.reply_id
        , m.reply_name
        , m.dt 
FROM    notes m 
        INNER JOIN user u ON m.user_id = u.user_id 
WHERE   u.user_id ='2' 
        AND m.dt < '2010-09-20_131830' 
ORDER BY m.dt DESC
```

Comment: thanks for a brillant answer, if i may ask another thing aswell, say i wanted to add third  query to the union, that will retrieve the same data set u.pictue, u.id etc. would that be okay?

Comment: It would be okay but it would also become less readable. Adding yet another UNION to the query would make it a good candidate to hide the dirty details behind a VIEW. You would gain readability at the expense of performance (the WHERE md.dt clause would again be outside the SELECT statement) so there's a tradeoff you have to consider.

Comment: im not really worried about readability as much as performance, so basically putting another union in thier would be better performance!!, sorry im a such newbie

Comment: Don't worry, we're all here to learn. I assume the performance was indeed better?